# Spring Boot: inserting mock Bean into Camel Processor unit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a Camel Processor in a Spring Boot application that I am trying to write unit test for. The processor class looks like this:

```
@Named
public class MyProcessor implements Processor {
    @Inject
    private MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
       ...
    }
}
```

I am trying to inject a mock MyService object into a unit test.

I have tried this:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyProcessorTest {
    @TestConfiguration
    static class Config {
        @Autowired
        private MyProcessor myProcessor;

        @Bean
        CamelContextConfiguration myProcessorTestContextConfiguration() {
            return new CamelContextConfiguration() {
                @Override
                public void beforeApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {
                    MyService myService = Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
                    camelContext.addService(myService);
                    ...
```

... but that doesn't seem to work - a non-mocked instance of MyService is injected into the processor. I think the issue is because my mocked service object is created in the Camel context, rather than via Spring.

Can anyone advise as to the correct approach here?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Yeah `@Inject` and `@Named` is spring annotation and its spring that creates and does dependency injection into that processor. So look for how to mock this with spring and you have a chance to find a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace Beans in SpringBootTest with Mocks by using `@MockBean`

```
@SpringBootTest
...
@MockBean 
private MyService myService;
```

This creates a Mockito Mock of type `MyService` in the Spring test context and (as a consequence) injects it where it would normally inject the real Bean.